# How to transform content inside a column

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, semantic-ui

guys. Currently I am building React Weather app (http://powerful-headland-90755.herokuapp.com/#/weather)

and I wanna to make those columns in the bottom flipping to show content on the back side. I encountered a problem, that this animation requires child elements to be absolutely positioned, that's why columns themselves become very low height. I have semantic ui grid, and want to flip those squares on hover.

Any suggestions about how to not break grid while making them transform? Will be glad to receive any help or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique is to make a div that takes up space, and render the actual card inside it which is absolutely positioned. You can then animate it without the grid item changing size.

```
<div style={{width: '10em', height: '25em'}}>
  <div style={{
    position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0,
    transform: something,
  }}>
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Inline styles used for example purposes.</sub>